# Google Cloud Endpoint insert from client app not working on local server

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I followed Google's tutorial on creating an Android client to post simple notes to an app engine backend using cloud endpoints as seen here:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-create-fromandroid

I ran the local server followed by the Android client app and all seems to work well. No errors are reported. But when I go to list the notes using curl or the API explorer, it returns an empty set.

I made sure to disable my virus scanner and turn off my firewall. No luck. I'm running the Android client on my phone (connected to my wifi network) if that makes a difference. I could never get the emulator to work, it just hangs at the boot screen forever, so I always use my phone.

Insert code is executed as an AsyncTask as per Google's instruction:

```
public class EndpointsTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, Long> {
    protected Long doInBackground(Context... contexts) {

      Noteendpoint.Builder endpointBuilder = new Noteendpoint.Builder(
          AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
          new JacksonFactory(),
          new HttpRequestInitializer() {
          public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) { }
          });
  Noteendpoint endpoint = CloudEndpointUtils.updateBuilder(
  endpointBuilder).build();
  try {
      Note note = new Note().setDescription("Note Description");
      String noteID = new Date().toString();
      note.setId(noteID);

      note.setEmailAddress("E-Mail Address");
      Log.e("Debug", "Inserting note...");
      Note result = endpoint.insertNote(note).execute();
      Log.e("Debug", "Done inserting note!");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
      return (long) 0;
    }
}
```

Of interest is that the "Done inserting note!" never prints. I put further debug into the insertNote function itself and it makes it all the way to the return statement. Not sure how it's possible that it's not returning?

Any suggestions on how I can solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you disable https on your local server? I think that this protocol doesn't work in development mode with Endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it is never connecting.  I am a little surprised that you aren't seeing the stacktrace.  Is it possible that you are filtering the stacktrace from the LogCat and not seeing it?

There are two things that you need to setup in order to connect to the local server over wifi (assuming firewall is disabled).

1. Using the example code generated by Eclipse.  In the DeviceInfoEndpoint class, you need to define an attribute for the annotation @Api, you need to set the **<server ip>** to the server ip.  My port is set to 8888 by Eclipse.

   ```
   @Api(root = "http://<server ip>:8888/_ah/api", name = "deviceinfoendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "gcetest.com", ownerName = "gcetest.com", packagePath = ""))
   public class DeviceInfoEndpoint {
   ```
2. As stated in the documentation below you will need to set the address option to 0.0.0.0 (-a is a shortcut for the --address option)

-a 0.0.0.0

See the documentation for the devserver https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver?csw=1

> --address=...
>   The host address to use for the server. You may need to set this to be able to access the >development server from another computer on your network. An address of 0.0.0.0 allows both >localhost access and hostname access. Default is localhost.

This can be done in Eclipse in the by

- Right-Clicking the project and selecting Properties
- Select "Run/Debug Settings"
- Select the app engine project
- Click the "Edit..." button
- Select the "Arguments" tab
- In "Program arguments:" textbox add "-a 0.0.0.0" after the --port 8888 setting

It should look something like this

--port=8888 -a 0.0.0.0

- Start the server
- Regenerate the endpoint for the client app
- Redeploy the client app

I think that should solve your problem.